# ZFS encrypted pool on Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, filesystems, encryption, zfs

I'm currently playing around and testing ZFS and I really like it. Now I am looking for the best way to use it as a replacement for my standard setup with luks-based full disk encryption.

How is the concept of encryption in ZFS, do I encrypt a whole *pool* or just individual *datasets*? My idea is to boot, enter a passphrase and the rest as usual. I do not want to enter a passphrase for every dataset in my pool, so is it possible?

I already tried using a ZFS pool inside a luks full disk encryption container, it works, but I guess this will be way less performant than using ZFS directly.

I'm using Arch Linux with the "Stable" kernel and an NVME SSD. Thanks for clarification and recommended setups!

Oh, one more: I read that you cannot encrypt existing datasets or pools, is that still the case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Encryption was added to ZFS On Linux with the release of version 0.8.  So you need at least that version.
- In ZFS, encryption is on a per-dataset basis, not on a pool - but, as with most things in ZFS, a dataset can inherit encryption properties from its parent (or from a defined `encryptionroot` instead of the parent).
- Setting encryption on a dataset in ZFS will **not** automatically encrypt any data already in it.   As with enabling compression (or changing the compression type), only new data will be encrypted.
- to encrypt existing data, you can `rsync` or `zfs send` it to another dataset with encryption enabled, and then replace the old dataset with the new encrypted one.  This may require the system to be in single-user mode (or, at least, to temporarily shut down any programs which may write to, or have files open on, the old dataset)

I don't use encryption on any of my zpools, so that's about all I know about it.  I'd strongly advise doing more research and reading the archives of the ZOL mailing lists and search for [encryption related issues](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+encryption+) on the [ZOL github repo](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs).

From the **Encryption** section of `man zfs`:

> **Encryption**
>
> Enabling the encryption feature allows for the creation of encrypted
>   filesystems and volumes.  ZFS will encrypt file and zvol data, file
>   attributes, ACLs, permission bits, directory listings, FUID mappings,
>   and `userused` / `groupused` data.  ZFS will not encrypt metadata
>   related to the pool structure, including dataset and snapshot names,
>   dataset hierarchy, properties, file size, file holes, and
>   deduplication tables (though the deduplicated data itself is
>   encrypted).
>
> Key rotation is managed by ZFS.  Changing the user's key (e.g. a
>   passphrase) does not require re-encrypting the entire dataset. 
>   Datasets can be scrubbed, resilvered, renamed, and deleted without the
>   encryption keys being loaded (see the `zfs load-key` subcommand for
>   more info on key loading).
>
> Creating an encrypted dataset requires specifying the `encryption` and
>   `keyformat` properties at creation time, along with an optional
>   `keylocation` and `pbkdf2iters`.  After entering an encryption key,
>   the created dataset will become an encryption root. Any descendant
>   datasets will inherit their encryption key from the encryption root by
>   default, meaning that loading, unloading, or changing the key for the
>   encryption root will implicitly do the same for all inheriting
>   datasets. If this inheritance is not desired, simply supply a
>   `keyformat` when creating the child dataset or use `zfs change-key` to
>   break an existing relationship, creating a new encryption root on the
>   child.
>
> Note that the child's `keyformat` may match that of the parent while
>   still creating a new `encryption` root, and that changing the
>   encryption property alone does not create a new encryption root; this
>   would simply use a different cipher suite with the same key as its
>   encryption root. The one exception is that clones will always use
>   their origin's encryption key.  As a result of this exception, some
>   encryption-related properties (namely `keystatus`, `keyformat`,
>   `keylocation`, and `pbkdf2iters`) do not inherit like other ZFS
>   properties and instead use the value determined by their encryption
>   root. Encryption root inheritance can be tracked via the **read-only**
>   `encryptionroot` property.
>
> Encryption changes the behavior of a few ZFS operations. Encryption is
>   applied after compression so compression ratios are preserved.
>   Normally checksums in ZFS are 256 bits long, but for encrypted data
>   the checksum is 128 bits of the user-chosen checksum and 128 bits of
>   MAC from the encryption suite, which provides additional protection
>   against maliciously altered data. Deduplication is still possible with
>   encryption enabled but for security, datasets will only dedup against
>   themselves, their snapshots, and their clones.
>
> There are a few limitations on encrypted datasets. Encrypted data
>   cannot be embedded via the `embedded_data` feature. Encrypted datasets
>   may not have copies=3 since the implementation stores some encryption
>   metadata where the third copy would normally be. Since compression is
>   applied before encryption, datasets may be vulnerable to a CRIME-like
>   attack if applications accessing the data allow for it. Deduplication
>   with encryption will leak information about which blocks are
>   equivalent in a dataset and will incur an extra CPU cost per block
>   written.

Comment: That sounds good, thanks. Nice to see these little details like encryption after compression and encryption inheritance, this is exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: @Robert Note that if ZFS encryption is like compression (it may not be fully - I haven't checked) you can just copy a file to encrypt it once encryption is enabled for a dataset - `cp -p filename filename.tmp; mv filename.tmp filename`.  That does break hard links, though.

Comment: I managed to get everything up and running with native ZFS encryption on root using zfs-dkms and systemd-boot. Feels good to have finally found a modern LUKS replacement for my systems.

Comment: @cas can you explain the `copies=3` thing? Does this mean that there is a storage overhead to using encryption? Is it not like LUKS / dm-crypt where there is a 1:1 sector ratio between plaintext and encrypted?

Comment: @starfry as i said, i don't use or know much about zfs encryption, but it looks like it is saying exactly that: there is some storage overhead.   given that it says "stores some encryption **metadata**", I'd expect the overhead to be fairly small.

Comment: I presume that [CRIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRIME) refers to information leakage based on how much the size changes. Could you add a link for "MAC from the encryption suite"? I couldn't figure out what that refers to